# Outlook 2007 + Exchange 2010 (Save All Attachments)

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2007, attachment

About 3 weeks back our company upgraded our mail system to Exchange 2010, all went smooth, few issues but nothing major.

A few days ago we had a call from a college where he was unable to save all attachments, From `File > Save As > Save All Attachments`.

When the email has a single attachment it works perfectly normal, and depending on the file type it allows you to save multiple attachments.

But there's a lot of file types that will not work, such as zip, pdf, doc etc, Usually we get a location box open up asking where we would like to drop the attachments, but it does nothing, You click `Save All Attachments` and nothing happens.

After hours of research I have come across mixed results, a lot of people on forums have been explaining that they have recently crossed over to Exchange 2010 and there issues started there.

But on the other hand Microsoft released a KB ([278188](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278188)) which was depressing if that, but that article was published in 2007, as stated by the time stamp, and Exchange 2010 has only come out recently.

Im looking to see if you guys have any clues what could be causing this, anything server side that I can take a look at (AD, Exchange, ...).

Any help on this is greatly supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has issued a hotfix, available [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2276479), for this issue.  It will be rolled into Outlook 2007 SP3 (whenever that's released).

From the article:

> Consider the following scenario: Your
>   mailbox is moved to Microsoft Exchange
>   Server 2010. In Office Outlook 2007,
>   you open an email message that
>   contains an attachment. The message
>   was sent by an external user. You
>   click the Microsoft Office button,
>   point to Save As, and then click Save
>   Attachments.
>
> In this scenario, the attachment is
>   not saved as expected.

Comment: Beautiful mate, I have passed this fix to my line manager, its about time they have a fix for this, +1 and accepted.